# codeigniter 3.0 like query add ESCAPE '!' on like

Tags: codeigniter, php-5.5, codeigniter-3

codeigniter 3.0 like query add ESCAPE '!'

example:

```
 $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('sample');
    $this->db->like('col','val%val2');
    $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

CI produces the query like following

```
SELECT * FROM `sample` WHERE `col` LIKE '%val!%val2%' ESCAPE '!'
```

But I expected it

```
SELECT * FROM `sample` WHERE `col` LIKE '%val%val2%'
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: I want a more polite question instead of a demand.

Comment: can you please improve your quesiton.Its little hard to understand or you may be want this `$this->db->like('col','val1%val2%val3','both',true);`

Comment: i edit question please check ..

Comment: @ShaifulIslam please check question now.

Comment: @ShaifulIslam yes i tried but that also not work same result return

Answer (score 2):

After searching I found that the answer, it will remove **'!' ESCAPE** sign from query

```
$this->db->like('category_name', $string,'both',false);
```

Answer (score 0):

AT CI-2 it produce the result as expected.But CI-3 Producing result as you said.May be it should be improve.

After some research I found solution where you need to set some config inside `system/database/DB_driver.php`

Open the the DB_driver.php go to line 340 and 347. You will find like this

```
protected $_like_escape_str = " ESCAPE '%s' ";

/**
 * ESCAPE character
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $_like_escape_chr = '!';
```

Change them to empty like following

```
protected $_like_escape_str = "";

/**
 * ESCAPE character
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $_like_escape_chr = '';
```

Comment: its may work but i can't chnage my system folder files.